# SQL Case statement throwing missing keyword error

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, oracle11g

I'm trying this query:

```
Select * from users_t t
where
case when sysdate <= to_date('20130131', 'yyyymmdd')
then t.user_id=1254664
else t.user_id=1259753
End
```

Why is it giving out "ORA-00905: missing keyword" error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a comparison operator *outside* the `case` statement:

```
Select * from users_t t
where
(case when sysdate <= to_date('20130131', 'yyyymmdd')
then 254664
else 1259753
End) = t.user_id
```

However, you can write this without the `case` statement:

```
select *
from users_t t
where ((sysdate <= to_date('20130131', 'yyyymmdd') and t.user_id = 254664) or
      ((sysdate > to_date('20130131', 'yyyymmdd') and t.user_id = 1259753)
```

Answer (score 3):

Your case statement is not correct.

```
SELECT * 
FROM users_t t
WHERE t.user_id = CASE WHEN SYSDATE <= TO_DATE('20130131', 'yyyymmdd')
                       THEN 1254664
                       ELSE 1259753
                  END
```

This will accomplish your task.

Edit: Better formatting.

Answer (score 1):

A `CASE` statement in SQL always returns a value. You need to equate this `CASE` statement to something. Read more about it [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/expressions004.htm).

You should use your code as following:

```
Select * from users_t t
where
t.user_id = case
                 when sysdate <= to_date('20130131', 'yyyymmdd')
                 then 1254664
                 else 1259753
            End
```

Answer (score 0):

The root cause of this error is that there is no Boolean data type in Oracle SQL.  (Which I personally think is a huge mistake.)

Returning a condition is a perfectly valid idea, and it even works in PL/SQL:

```
declare
    v_test Boolean;
begin
    v_test := case when 1=1 then 1=1 else 1=2 end;
end;
/
```